# Rewrite URL appending unwanted parameter to end of new URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've implemented this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pBrand=GRAVIS$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^brand\.php$ /brand/gravis/ [R=301,L]
```

The redirect works fine however, the end result is:

http://site.com.au/brand/gravis/?pBrand=GRAVIS

The problem is that, I don't want to have the `?pBrand=GRAVIS` appended. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Have you tried removing pBrand=GRAVIS from your rewrite rule?

Comment: I'd try dropping the `R` flag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOu need a `?` to remove the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pBrand=GRAVIS$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^brand\.php$ /brand/gravis/? [R=301,L]
```

Normally, the query string gets appended automatically, but if you have a `?` in the target, the query string doesn't get appended unless you have the `QSA` flag.

Comment: Thanks, if I have multiple brands, do I have to repeat those two lines for each brand?

Comment: @Joe yeah, the other thing you can do is try to match the `GRAVIS` part of the query string, then back reference it using `%1` and maybe use a rewrite map to change it to lower case